# Gridview Header customizing issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

If we add a customer header to the `gridview`, will it add extra row?

Currently I have a `gridview` with `four` columns and, when I add a custom header `gridview` coming with a `five` rows.

My code looks like this...

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="4%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
          <HeaderTemplate>
              <asp:DropDownList ID="Select" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>Country</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Region</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Title</asp:ListItem>
              </asp:DropDownList>
          </HeaderTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>  

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="4%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:HiddenField ID="Id"  Value='<%#Eval("id")%>' runat="server" />  
             <asp:Literal ID="ltrImage" runat="server"></asp:Literal>  
        </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

and three other `TemplateFields`...

Is there any problem of adding header this way? Any other way to add customer header without having this issue? 
My desired output should look like this

```
Search Result   Search By (Dropdownlist)
Data column1    Data column2             Data column3     Data column4
```

The one I am getting now is

```
Sort By (Dropdownlist)  
                       Data column1   Data column2  Data column3    Data column4
```

Could anyone help if have an idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You just added another column with custom header to your gridview. If you want to customize a header of the first column, just customize the header of your first template field:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="4%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
         <HeaderTemplate>
              <asp:DropDownList ID="Select" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>Country</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Region</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Title</asp:ListItem>
              </asp:DropDownList>
         </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:HiddenField ID="Id"  Value='<%#Eval("id")%>' runat="server" />  
             <asp:Literal ID="ltrImage" runat="server"></asp:Literal>  
        </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

If this dropdownlist is too big or if you want add some additional text in the header, you can always create HeaderTemplate for other TemplateFields of merge some of the column's headers in code behind (example for "merging" two first headers, Id of the gridView is `gridView1`):

```
protected void gridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int indexOfColumnToSpan = 0;
    int indexOfColumnToRemoveHeader = 1;
    gridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[indexOfColumnToSpan].ColumnSpan = 2;  
    gridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.RemoveAt(indexOfColumnToRemoveHeader);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you have not actually added a header row, but a header column .. which is basically just another column with more controls ..

why dont you place your DropDownList before your GridView, and then you can write some code behind handling the DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged event to sort the Data ?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this without using the filters within the GridView. Then you can handle the events separately, and populate the GridView accordingly.

What you are actually adding is a column, instead of a row. That's why you are getting that result.

Hope this helps!